# In cmd on Windows stop WHERE command after first file found

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to run R from cmd and am using the following to find the executable:

```
WHERE /R C:\ Rscript.exe
```

This returns multiple exe files but I only want the first one so is there any way to tell the command to stop after it finds one?

Thank you.

Comment: No. The commands are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where_1)

Comment: Just execute your command. The first one will be used. That is what `where` tells you.

Comment: As a work-around you could use this: `set "FIRST=" & for /F "delims= eol=|" %E in ('where /R C:\ Rscript.exe') do @if not defined FIRST set "FIRST=%E"`, so variable `FIRST` will hold the first item then (use `echo/%FIRST%` to view)...

Comment: @aschipfl That's perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for /F` loop, capture the output of `where` and ignore all but the first items:

```cmd
set "FIRST=" & for /F "delims= eol=|" %E in ('where /R C:\ Rscript.exe') do @if not defined FIRST set "FIRST=%E"
```

The variable `FIRST` will hold the first item then (use `echo/%FIRST%` or `set FIRST` to view).

Remember to use `%%E` instead of `%E` when you want to integrate this code into a batch file.